# What is the recommended coffee bean to water ratio for drip brewing?

Tags: beans

I recently bought a coffee grinder and I want to know the how much coffee bean to grind to produce a perfect cup of coffee.

Comment: Welcome to Coffee SE, please feel free to take the [tour](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/tour). Your question is not clear to me. Do you ask this question for the french press or for espresso? IS it related to the grinder or with the brewing process itself?

Comment: I meant a drip coffee maker. I want to know the ratio of coffee bean to water like 1 tablespoon to 1 cup of water. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very basics of French press brewing is: 10-12 grams of coffee for 200-250 ml of 90-95 °Celsius water for 2-4 minutes.

*You may simply note that as 1:20 coffee to water ratio.*